# How can I disable material ui css classes and force to use inline style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use material-ui component with inline style. Components are rendered  with  **.jss1 .jss2** etc classes in html code. Is there a way disable generating classes and using inline style in html?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to disable generating classes?

Comment: ın order to security consideration i  cannot use iframe, so I decide to render react application in ASP.NET MVC site and I do not want to affect asp.net site by material ui css classes.

Comment: What version of Material-UI are you using?

Comment: If you are concerned that the "jss" prefix could occur in classes already in use in your site, it is possible to change the prefix. It is not possible to change it to use inline styles for the default component styling. In v4, the classes for the default styling are not minimized to use the "jss" prefix and instead look like "MuiFormControl-root" or similar, but if you use `withStyles` or `makeStyles` in your own code, those classes would still get the "jss" prefix if you haven't customized the prefix.